# best practice to replace css float, is it position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have read somewhere that floating is not recommended except for its initial usage, which is to float images around text.

So I conclude that, to make my child div stay at the right of my parent div, instead of using

```
child-div {
  float: right;
}
```

I should use

```
parent-div {
  position: relative;
}
child-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Is this the best practice to replace float?

What if i have 5 child elements in one row? What should i use to replace float?

Thanks.
In case this question duplicates others, let me know

Comment: use `float` property like this situation, `position:absolute` not good for this area ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float is perfectly fine for what you're doing, so long as you clear the containing div to avoid layout issues.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">Some text</div>
    <div class="child-div">Some text</div>
    <div class="child-div">Some text</div>
    <div class="child-div">Some text</div>
    <div class="child-div">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
.parent-div:after { clear: both; display: table; content: ""; }
.child-div { float: left; }
```

Alternatively, you can use `display: inline-block` instead of float.

Comment: thank you, Linda. Could you explain a bit more one on 'display:inline-block'?

Comment: Sure! It gives elements the properties of display:block but inlines them. This way you don't need to clear your container.

You can read more about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp

Beware though! It's only supported in IE8 and above. So if you need IE7 support stick with float.

Answer (score 3):

You can user flexbox in 2016;

```css
.parent { display: flex; justify-content: flex-end }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div style="background:red">000</div>
  <div style="background:green">111</div>
  <div style="background:yellow">222</div>
  <div style="background:tomato">333</div>
</div>
```

Ofc you can add some styles so they have some space between them (child divs)

Comment: thank you, shadow. just read up a few sites on flex based on your recommendation. it is a great solution. only that, it may not support old browser and my old libraries, which could be another issue. so i decided not to use it.